# What is the correct use of "key" in the min() function?

Tags: python, min

I have a question about the min() function in Python. I am confused about the use of the "key" option in min(). Could someone explain how key works in min(), especially in relation to a lambda function?

For example:

```
lst = [10, -5, 20, 1]
min(lst, key=lambda x: x > 0)
```

As far as I understand, this expression should find the minimum element in the list lst that is greater than zero. However, it returns -5 instead of 1, which is the minimum element of lst that is greater than zero. Can someone explain why this happens and how I should correctly use key in the min() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key function `key=lambda x: x > 0` just evaluates to a Boolean. You can see this you you write it out in a loop:

```
lst = [10, -5, 20, 1]
for item in lst:
    print(item > 0)
```

Booleans are subclasses of integers, so the conversion is easy:

```
lst = [10, -5, 20, 1]
for item in lst:
    print(int(item > 0))
```

Guess what; `-5` is the only value that returns `False` (`0`) so that's the result you get as the minimum (that was your key).

You could `filter` this list but, really, you'd just be better re-building it with positive elements and then using `min()` without a `key`, to be clear on what you're doing:

```
lst = [10, -5, 20, 1]
lst = [item for item in lst if item > 0]
print(min(lst))
```